# Why I am getting Notice: Undefined index: CIRReportData JSON PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

```
  <?php
  $response = '{
"CCRResponse": {
    "Status": "1",
    "CIRReportDataLst": [
        {
            "CIRReportData": {
                "IDAndContactInfo": {
                    "PersonalInfo": {
                        "Name": {
                            "FullName": "URMILA GUPTA ",
                            "FirstName": "URMILA ",
                            "LastName": "GUPTA "
                        },
                        " AliasName": {},
                        "DateOfBirth": "1951-11-05"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
    }';
   $r1 = json_encode(json_decode($response), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
  $obj = json_decode($response, true);
     foreach ($obj["CCRResponse"]["CIRReportDataLst"] as $key) {
     echo $fullname = $key["CIRReportData"]["IDAndContactInfo"]["PersonalInfo"]["Name"] 
   ["FullName"];
        }?>
```

Can any help me why I am getting

> Notice: Undefined index: CIRReportData error?

I am able to get a response from my code but still getting errors.
You can find the full code here. Stack overflow doesn't all me to post full
https://app.box.com/s/sxt0eygha3ltx9bc59u0kn0kf0qqfzcm

Comment: It;s working fine in my side 
which php version are you using?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/7lYPK check here...

Comment: Can't reproduce this, as others have said. The code you've shown us works perfectly with the data you've shown us. If you need help, please double-check your post and ensure you have provided a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: Sorry, You can find the complete code here. Stack Overflow doesn't allow me to post full code https://app.box.com/s/sxt0eygha3ltx9bc59u0kn0kf0qqfzcm

Comment: Still not reproducible, even with a (usable subset of) that data: https://3v4l.org/gZqJ1

Comment: As if by magic. What did you change?

Comment: Actually, the code you are running is short when I run the code it is not running put my whole code into 3v4l.org then you can see the errors                        URMILA GUPTA 
Warning: Undefined array key "CIRReportData" in /tmp/preview on line 1093

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /tmp/preview on line 1093

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /tmp/preview on line 1093

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /tmp/preview on line 1093

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in

Comment: code link -> https://onecompiler.com/php/3yw56bpv8

Comment: I had to shorten the dataset because it would not let me load the whole data in 3v4l, it crashed saying the script was too big. So I think that misled me. Have you actually looked closely at your JSON at any point? When I inspected it in detail just now, I noticed that there are two entries in the CIRReportDataLst array, but only the first item has a field called CIRReportData in it. So when it loops and processes the second item, it fails because it cannot find that item. You will need to make your code check that CIRReportData is set first before trying to access it.

Comment: Honestly, ADyson I don't know how to do it. That's why I asked the question. I am sorry. I am not professional at all I am learning. Thanks for help.

Comment: You can use the `isset()` function to check if a variable or array item exists. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: Can you please write the code?

Comment: I tried this and it didn't give any response https://onecompiler.com/php/3yw5dv9mk

Comment: You have misunderstood what `continue;` does (I suggest you read the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) for it). You don't need that anyway...just put the `echo` inside the `if` block. I also doubt that you want to `break;` - unless you want your loop to stop if it doesn't find the item on the first try?

Comment: P.S. As an aside, I assume you realise that the line `$r1 = json_encode(json_decode($response), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);` is completely useless? You can just remove that.

Comment: Thank you, It is working completely fine now thanks so much ADyson. I also remove the line

Comment: Great. You should post your working solution as an Answer below, for the benefit of future readers (and also for the benefit of your reputation points :-) ).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251431/discussion-between-yuvraj-agawani-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($obj["CCRResponse"]["CIRReportDataLst"] as $key) {
  if (isset($key["CIRReportData"]["IDAndContactInfo"]["PersonalInfo"]["Name"]["FullName"])) {
    echo $key["CIRReportData"]["IDAndContactInfo"]["PersonalInfo"]["Name"]["FullName"];
  }
}
```

It worked for me.